# how to remove compiled Citadel?

Tags: linux, bash

I used wget to install Citadel on my Pi (compiling the sources), now i want to uninstall it.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove citadel-server
sudo apt-get purge citadel-server
```

but it doesn't work.
I am a not an expert of linux.

Any solutions?

Comment: `wget` is used mostly for downloading. How exactly did you install Citadel? apt-get will not work, if it was not installed through apt package system.

Comment: i used the easy install  `wget -q -O - http://easyinstall.citadel.org/install | bash`

Comment: At same location there's also `uninstall`, but it's not very useful ("Citadel may not be uninstalled using this method."). A quick web search comes up with http://www.citadel.org/how_do_i_uninstall_citadel.html Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  the  right process:

```
sudo systemctl stop citadel.service
sudo systemctl disable citadel.service
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/citadel.service
sudo rm /usr/lib/systemd/system/citadel.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl reset-failed
```

Then :

```
sudo rm -rf   /usr/local/citadel
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/webcit
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/ctdlsupport
```

Check :

```
sudo systemctl status citadel
```

The  service  may not  run again.

Answer (score 1):

A quick web search comes up with http://citadel.org/how_do_i_uninstall_citadel.html

Which says that in case of easy install you only need to delete following folders:

- /usr/local/citadel
- /usr/local/webcit
- /usr/local/ctdlsupport

You can use `rm -r` to delete folders and their contents.

Comment: I have followed the instructions here. However, the service is still trying to run when I use `systemctl status citadel`. Every few seconds my Raspberry Pi 4 blinks green indicating that data is being written. I checked the systemd logs and Citadel and Webcit fails to run as I removed the directories listed in the answer. Is there another way to uninstall citadel?